# How I can add icon from svelte-icons by name?

Tags: svelte, vite

I have a svelte project:

```
<script>
  import * as gIcons from 'svelte-icons/gi';
</script>

<gIcons src={filter.icon} />  // GiAirplane
```

Question: How I can add icon from svelte-icons by name ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work if the variable matches an export in `gIcons`:

```html
<svelte:component this={gIcons[filter.icon]} />
```

[Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-component)